# PhotoViewer plugin only shows black screen or crashes on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, photoviewer

I'm using Ionic 4 (4.12.0) with the PhotoViewer plugin versions:

```
"@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.21.5",
"com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.4",
```

And the code is:

```
 public presentImage(imgSrc): void {
    this.photoViewer.show(imgSrc, '', {
      share: false,
      closeButton: true,
      copyToReference: true
    });
  }
```

The variable **imgSrc** is a base64. If I remove the options, the photoViewer opens with a black screen, but with the options it's crashing the app. But as the title states, it only happens on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

after read the document, base64 is just supported on android. So it is what the problem. 
`(1.1.4) Base64 Support on Android`

Comment: And what do you recommend me using? Because we make the call to the backend which send us the image in a BLOB format and we convert it to base64 to show both on HTML and through the plugin when clicked.

Comment: use can use <img> tag to show base64 string like this:
`data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64String` and assign for src attribute